Detect double tap on split resizing button (screen divider) in split-screen mode
Prehistory:
The Multi-Window Mode's screen divider view has the following options:

if you drag the divider view, it will change the window sizes accordingly:

if you double tap on it, it will switch applications from current locations to the opposite sides:


Imagine that Google Maps app is my custom Android app:

Is there a way to detect the double tap/click on the Screen Divider view or detect application window switch in Split-Screen? Is there an appropriate listener or method to override? Is it possible to find the necessary code in AOSP?

At least I tried:
override fun onTopResumedActivityChanged(isTopResumedActivity: Boolean)

And inside it I used:
if (isTopResumedActivity && isInMultiWindowMode) { ... }

Unfortunately, it detects only clicks within applications' windows. So

isTopResumedActivity = true // clicked within my app


isTopResumedActivity = false // clicked within another app

Of course it's because of the belonging to my custom application's scope, not the whole System UI. Anyway, maybe someone already managed to do it.
Thanks in advance!
